# I can't complete the integration of $e^{\sqrt{x}}$

Tags: integration, exponential-function

> Compute $\displaystyle\int_0^1e^{\sqrt{x}}\,dx$

[image]

That's a picture of how far I could get while trying to integrate $e^{\sqrt{x}}$. I tried the substitution method first, (boxed part) and then went for the parts one, the problem is that when I want to find $V$, I need to integrate the starting function, so in the end I'm looped. Maybe I was doing something wrong, thanks for the help before hand.

Comment: [This page](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) includes info on how to type mathematics properly on this site so you can type things like $\int e^{\sqrt{x}}dx$.

Answer (score 7):

**Hint**. One may just make the change of variable
$$
u=\sqrt{x},\quad x=u^2,\quad dx=2udu
$$ giving
$$
\int e^{\sqrt{x}}dx=2\int ue^udu
$$ which may be evaluated by parts, thus

> $$
> \int e^{\sqrt{x}}dx=2(\sqrt{x}-1)e^{\sqrt{x}}+C,
> $$

for any constant $C$.

Answer (score 2):

Consider the change of variable $\sqrt x = t$. This turns tour integral into

$$\int \limits _0 ^1 \Bbb e ^{\sqrt x} \ \Bbb d x = \int \limits _0 ^1 \Bbb e ^t 2t \ \Bbb d t$$

which can now be integrated by parts:

$$2 \int \limits _0 ^1 \Bbb e ^t t \ \Bbb d t = 2 t \Bbb e^t \Big| _0 ^1 - 2 \int \limits _0 ^1 \Bbb e ^t = 2 \Bbb e - 2 \Bbb e ^t \Big| _0 ^1 = 2 \Bbb e - (2 \Bbb e - 2) = 2 .$$